# How to load a new view in the current view?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have angular 8 and a link that will create a new view.

The current link is like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea
```

and the new view is like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/new/Interview
```

But so I want that:

```
...\item/new/Interview
```

will be loaded in the same view as: So replaced

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea
```

So that the new will not be loaded in a totally new view.

So this I have as template view.component:

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
  <mat-icon class="interviews">speaker_notes</mat-icon>
  <span i18n>Interview reports</span>
{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.Interview) }}
   <a [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item', 'new', itemTypes.Interview]"
     >
      <mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
    </a>
</ng-template>
```

And this I have as route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'list',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossiers: DossierListResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: NewComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':dossierId/item/new/:dossierItemType',
    component: ItemComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: ':dossierId/item/:dossierItemId',
    component: ItemComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
];
```

and this is the item.component:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.itemType">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="itemTypes.Interview">
                <mat-icon class="interviews">speaker_notes</mat-icon>
                <span i18n>Interview:</span>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="itemTypes.Note">
                <mat-icon class="notes">note</mat-icon>
                <span i18n>Note:</span>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="itemTypes.Goal">
                <mat-icon class="goals">grade</mat-icon>
                <span i18n>Goal:</span>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="itemTypes.ActionStep">
                <mat-icon class="action-steps">list</mat-icon>
                <span i18n>ActionStep:</span>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <span>{{ item.title}}</span>
      </mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>
        <span *ngIf="!createdAtEqualsDate(item)">{{item.date | date: 'shortDate'}} <ng-template i18n>created</ng-template></span>
        <span>{{item.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="item.createdAt !== item.lastModifiedAt"><ng-template i18n>modified</ng-template> {{item.lastModifiedAt | date: 'short'}}</span>
      </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemForm; context: {item: item, formGroup: editItemForm, globalErrors: globalErrors}"></ng-container>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button *ngIf="!editItemForm.pristine" mat-raised-button (click)="cancel()" i18n>Cancel</button>
        <button *ngIf="editItemForm.pristine" mat-raised-button (click)="cancel()" i18n>Back</button>
        <button *ngIf="!isNew" mat-raised-button color="primary" [appSubmitIfValid]="editItemForm" (valid)="save()" i18n>Update</button>
        <button *ngIf="isNew" mat-raised-button color="primary" [appSubmitIfValid]="editItemForm" (valid)="save()" i18n>Create</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

if I do this

```
     <a [routerLink]="'/'+ dossier.id + '/item/new'+ itemTypes.Interview">
```

I get this error:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/newInterview'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/newInterview'
```

I already made a child component of it:

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent, children:[
    {  path: ':dossierId/item/:dossierItemId,', component: ItemComponent}
    ],
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
```

if I do this:

```
 <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <mat-icon class="goals">grade</mat-icon>
          <span i18n>Goals</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.Goal) }}
          <a routerLink="{{dossier.id}}/item/new/{{itemTypes.Goal}}"
            ><mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
          </a>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.Goal }"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
```

and this routerlink:

```
  {
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent, children:[
    {  path: ':dossierId/item/:dossierItemId,', component: ItemComponent}
    ],
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
```

I still get this error:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/new/Interview'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/new/Interview'
```

Comment: Did you tried nested routes?

Comment: How? Can you give example.Thank you

Comment: Maybe this could help: 
https://angular.io/guide/router#a-crisis-center-with-child-routes

Comment: Somebody any advice?

Comment: Can you share it on stack blitz?

Answer (score 1):

Please concat yout path like this way.

```
<a routerLink="{{item.id}}/item/new/{{item.name}}">
    <mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
</a>
```

with **app.routing.module.ts** path like this

```
{
    path: 'home/:id/item/new/:data', component:LoginComponent
},
```

try this it should work.

[image]

Comment: Do you have other suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Somebody any idea?

Comment: @thakor You have other suggestion?

Comment: @CodeIsNice, please check my answer i have edited with screenshot of demo and it is working fine,So please check it.

Comment: HI Thakor, can we go to chat

Comment: @thakor. Are you there?

Comment: Yes, I am here now

Comment: But better if I can sent you oke.

Comment: This is my email: niels.fischereinie@gmail.com

Comment: @thakor. Can you sent me email

Comment: @Thakor. But can you sent me email? Then I can sent you oke