# routing, first part is missing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routerlink

I have this routerlink:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/' + dossier.id + '/item/new' + itemTypes.Interview">
  <mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
</a>
```

but I get this error:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/newInterview'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/new/Interview'
```

Because the actul link is like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/new/interview
```

But how to correct this?

Thank you

this is routerconfig:

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent, children:[
    {  path: ':dossierId/item/:dossierItemId,', component: ItemComponent}
    ],
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
```

But I want to load the new item in the same view as view.component. See:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809692/how-to-load-a-new-view-in-the-current-view?noredirect=1#comment107589622_60809692
```

Comment: is it working with normal id? like: `1`?

Comment: What's your router config?

Answer (score 0):

There is a **/** missing in your code:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/' + dossier.id + '/item/new/' + itemTypes.Interview">
  <mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
<a [routerLink]={'/' + ${dossier.id} + '/item/new' + itemTypes.Interview}>
     <mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
</a>
```

Comment: With React it should work. What frameworks or libraries you are using?

Comment: I am using Angular 8